# Как отловить данные, которые передают программы на одной машине?

Tags: linux

Есть две программы на одной машине, они передают данные между собой по TCP, мне надо отловить эти данные. Есть ли программы для этого?

Comment: WireShark?

Comment: Тогда вопрос, как его настроить, чтобы он видел именно передачу, что не проходит через сетевую карту? Внутреннюю.

Comment: Указать интерфейс _lo_

Comment: @1101_debian А про tcpdump уже никто и не вспомнит...

@sercxjo Кроме указания интерфейса всё равно надо будет фильтр описывать. А то через lo много чего может бегать.

Answer (score 1):

Если знаешь какие порты используются, то можешь воспользоваться `tcpdump(tcpdump -XX -i lo tcp port YOUR_PORT)` или wireshark (в граф интерфейсе можно задать правила фильтрации).